# How to set a fixed position of my elements in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set elements stay on the edge of left and right hand side of the screen no matter what device or screen size is.

I am using bootstrap and have something like

```
<a href='#' id='prev' class='btn btn-primary'>left button</a>

<a href='#' id='next' class='btn btn-primary'>right button</a>
```

My css is like

```
#prev{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
}

#next{
    position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
    left: 95%;
}
```

I want something like

```
left button(edge of screen)                           right button(edge of screen)
```

Left button seems fine but my problem is right button.
My css only works for certain screen size but not all. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `right` property:

```
#prev{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

#next{
    position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
    right: 0;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6gw3K/

Answer (score 0):

Use right: 0 for #next

```
#prev{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

#next{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that position fixed is not a hard requirement, you might look into using floating. E.g.:

```
#pref{ float:left; }
#next{ float: right; }
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpNnQ/1/).